# How can I work with 100,000+ lines of text in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, realm

Xcode keeps crashing when I try to paste in even just 10,000 lines of text.

Basically I am trying to get a Chinese dictionary into a Realm.io database. Here is sample text:

```
var word993 = Word(); word993.traditional = "三尖杉酯鹼"; word993.simplified = "三尖杉酯碱"; word993.pinyin = "[san1 jian1 shan1 zhi3 jian3]"; word993.english = "/harringtonine (chemistry)/"; chineseEnglishDictionary.addObject(word993);
var word994 = Word(); word994.traditional = "三屜桌"; word994.simplified = "三屉桌"; word994.pinyin = "[san1 ti2 zhuo1]"; word994.english = "/three-drawer desk (traditional Chinese piece of furniture)/"; chineseEnglishDictionary.addObject(word994);
var word995 = Word(); word995.traditional = "三山"; word995.simplified = "三山"; word995.pinyin = "[San1 shan1]"; word995.english = "/Sanshan district of Wuhu city 蕪湖市|芜湖市[Wu2 hu2 shi4], Anhui/"; chineseEnglishDictionary.addObject(word995);
var word996 = Word(); word996.traditional = "三山區"; word996.simplified = "三山区"; word996.pinyin = "[San1 shan1 qu1]"; word996.english = "/Sanshan district of Wuhu city 蕪湖市|芜湖市[Wu2 hu2 shi4], Anhui/"; chineseEnglishDictionary.addObject(word996);
var word997 = Word(); word997.traditional = "三岔口"; word997.simplified = "三岔口"; word997.pinyin = "[San1 cha4 kou3]"; word997.english = "/At the Crossroads, famous opera, based on a story from 水滸傳|水浒传[Shui3 hu3 Zhuan4]/"; chineseEnglishDictionary.addObject(word997);
var word998 = Word(); word998.traditional = "三島由紀夫"; word998.simplified = "三岛由纪夫"; word998.pinyin = "[San1 dao3 You2 ji4 fu1]"; word998.english = "/Mishima Yukio (1925-1970), Japanese author, pen name of (平岡公威|平冈公威, Hiraoka Kimitake)/"; chineseEnglishDictionary.addObject(word998);
var word999 = Word(); word999.traditional = "三峽"; word999.simplified = "三峡"; word999.pinyin = "[San1 xia2]"; word999.english = "/Three Gorges on the Chang Jiang or Yangtze, namely: Qutang Gorge 瞿塘峽|瞿塘峡[Qu1 tang2 Xia2], Wuxia Gorge 巫峽|巫峡[Wu1 Xia2]; chineseEnglishDictionary.addObject(word999);
```

How can I work with this many lines of code without crashing?

Comment: If you are going to down vote this, at least tell me why. Thanks.

Comment: A good parser should be able to parse much more. There is probably a bug in you parser. I assume this `chineseEnglishDictionary.addObject(...)` is the problem. You can not fit all the data in RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no clue as to why XCode crashes or information about the crash.
But instead of entering the text programmatically, I would suggest you make a text file with each word-set comma seperated on a seperate line, then make a small program that opens the file, and iterates over the lines and inserts them into the realm one by one. Then you can just include the database-file in you program.